# How can i add two components to my screen without them overlapping and only showing one?

Tags: java, jframe, jcomponent

Right now i can only have one of my two components show up on the screen the second one always just overlaps the first so the second is only showing.

How can I get both of them to show up at the same time.

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Amazing {

private final int width = 300;
private final int height = width / 16 * 9;
private int scale = 3;
private static Graphics g;

private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public Amazing(){
    Dimension size = new Dimension(width*scale, height*scale);
    frame.setPreferredSize(size);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setTitle("Amazing!");
    Character character = new Character(50,50,scale,width,height);
    Map map = new Map(scale, width, height);
    frame.add(map);
    frame.add(character);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    character.requestFocus();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Amazing amazing = new Amazing();
}

}
```

I figured you don't need to see the other two classes(if you want i can also post them) but I think all you need to know about them are that the map class creates and paints with `paintComponent(Graphics g)` 2 randomly generated rectangles while the Character class creates and uses the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method to show and Image on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify a layout, you were using BorderLayout which only displays 1 component in each section. Unless you specify a different location as an additional arg when using the default BorderLayout, the add(component) method will "overwrite" whatever was there previously. Therefore, when you add your second component to your frame it overwrites the first.

I noticed that you imported GridLayout, but i don't see it used in your code. If you add a statement in the constructor like:

this.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));

it will change the layout from the default BorderLayout to the GridLayout, and you will have 4 rows of 2 compartments each in which to place components. Calling the add(component) method will add a component in the next available section, starting with row 1 spot 1.

If you only want to add those two items, try putting in the statement

this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

before you add your components. This will place them side by side.

Comment: *"A frame can only hold 1 component"* is not entirely true, in fact, by default, it can hold as many as you want, but it will only display one for each of the 5 available spaces uses by BorderLayout...

Answer (score 0):

When adding components to a panel in Swing you should choose a `LayoutManager` for the panel (`FlowLayout` is simple, `GridBoxLayout` flexible, but there are many more). Depending on the layout chosen you also associate data with the component to tell the `LayoutManager` where to place the component.

Answer (score 0):

The "main" problem you're having is the fact that by default `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout`.  `BorderLayout` will only only a single component to occupy each of its five available positions.  By default, `BorderLayout` will place components at the `CENTER` position.

You should explore a different layout manager which meets your requirements.

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)